# Why is python's sqlite3 module trying to import datetime from my project directory?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-module

I'm trying to follow the example the [python manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) gives for interfacing with SQLite. This first line of code seems to not be working correctly:

```
import sqlite3
```

So trying to import python's sqlite3 module is trying to import python's datetime from the calling scripts directory instead of wherever it lives, as seen from the traceback below. I cant figure out why. What am I missing?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlite_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 24, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/home/brian/dev/py/datetime.py", line 3, in <module>
    now = datetime.now()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rename `/home/brian/dev/py/datetime.py` module to something other than `datetime.py`, cause it has the same name with the datetime builtin module.

Please avoid naming your modules with the same name as standard-library or built-in module names.

Comment: Thank you... I wont make that mistake again.

Answer (score 2):

In a little more detail, there is a Python built-in module called `datetime`, which is used to manage -- well, you know.

You've created a file called `datetime.py`, which corresponds to a module called `datetime`. Since `sqlite` wants to use the Python built-in `datetime` module, it imports it -- but the fact that you have created a file with the same name in the same directory means that Python's prioritisation rules will choose that over the builtin.

As an analogy, if you'd created a file `sqlite3.py` in your working directory, `import sqlite3` would give you that module instead of the builtin one.

Moral of the story: don't shadow built-in names.